# Best practice for tracking merging hotfixes

Tags: jira, tracking

We are working with two main branches in our project, a development branch and a production branch. All production fixes get their own hotfix branch, which is then merged back into the development branch when all tests pass and the customer/client validates the ticket is correct.

As a result, sometimes the merging step doesn't happen until later. The consequence of this is that at times the merging step is forgotten. Right now we track the hotfix ticket in JIRA but nothing really tracks the merging part of the task.

What would be a good way to track the merging step for a hotfix? We could do a sub-task in the original ticket but that would mean that ticket can't be closed till the merging happens. Would a new ticket just to track this merging step be the right way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another site, perhaps [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What my Team does is we have a status (and a column) for both 'Waiting for Merge' and 'Merged'.

> We could do a sub-task in the original ticket but that would mean that ticket can't be closed till the merging happens

I don't see why you would *want* the issue to be 'Done' before all the work needed for it to go live is *done*. Do you have a Definition of Done? If not, your Team should develop one, and consider putting 'Merged to Production Branch' as part of it.